# running two bash commands simultaneously on two different computers from one script

Tags: multithreading, bash

I have a client and a host program (written in c) which I want to run from two different remote locations simultaneously.  Since I have to do this some 50 times to gather data, I don't want to have to run them individually.  On one side, I need to log in via ssh, start the script and tell it to write the output to a file.  Then I need to log into another box via ssh and tell it to send the data, and then repeat the whole process another 49 times.

I figure what I need is to do is run the two commands from two separate windows.

How do I tell a single bash script to spawn two windows, input separate commands into each window and then come back to the parent window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your client and host each need terminals, you should be able to background them, especially if your output is going to a file.

```
ssh user@machine1 host_prog args > output file &
ssh user@machine2 client_prog args &
```

Comment: thanks.  I just discovered this myself, but I also didn't know that you could start a command from the ssh line.

Comment: important thing to add: you might want to get the pid from the process so you can wait on it finishing.  The pid is stored in $# after each process is spawned.